# How to write xpath or cssSelector for a material-ui webelement if the element disappears

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, material-ui, dropdown, webdriver-io

Following is such an element(textbox):

```html
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="multiple-limit-tags" required="" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedEnd" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="">
```

When I click in this textbox, a dropdown opens and following attribute appears

```
aria-activedescendant='multiple-limit-tags-option-0' (this 0 to 20)
```

But when I try to right-click and click anywhere, the dropdown closes.
Unable to capture them with xPath[image: SampleUI]

Comment: I tried using SelectorsHub chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorshub/ndgimibanhlabgdgjcpbbndiehljcpfh/related?hl=en
But getting blank values

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the textbox and then try using key press events and select the value.

Answer (score 0):

MUI Material UI dropdown components use **'focusout'** event listener to hide the element if user clicks elsewhere.
You will be able to stop hiding these elements when you delete the links inside this event listener.

[Event Listener Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QThxW.png)